# How to link a url in a javascript image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to put a href in the image to link with a url, this would be done in the three images that contain the code below. When someone "click" on the image go to another page.

```
<div class="header_slider">    
<script src="{{skin url=''}}js/camera.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  /* index slider */
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#camera_wrap').camera({
      alignmen: 'topCenter',
      height: '32.882%',
      minHeight: '50px',
      loader : false,
      fx: 'simpleFade',
      navigationHover:false,
      thumbnails: false,
      playPause: false 
    });
  });
// ]]></script>
<div class="fluid_container">
  <div class="camera_wrap camera_orange_skin" id="camera_wrap">
    <div data-src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slideshow/banner1.png"}}">
      <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
        <div class="right_slider_side sl_1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div  data-src="{{media 
url="wysiwyg/slideshow/OfertaCarrossel_Kits_0002.005.00020.jpg" }}">
      <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
        <div class="right_slider_side sl_2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div  data-src="{{media     url="wysiwyg/slideshow/OfertaCarrossel_Sofa_0006.004.00021_FIN.jpg"}}">
      <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
        <div class="right_slider_side sl_3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Place `onclick="window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779222/how-to-link-a-url-in-a-javascrit-image'"` in your divs that start like `<div data-src`...

Answer (score 2):

You could add a class on each div with `data-src` tag and use JQuery on click event to redirect them to another page.  Add another data tag to store the destination url.

For example on the HTML

```
<div class="clickMe" data-destination="http://www.google.com" data-src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slideshow/banner1.png"}}">
```

And your Javascript

```
$('.clickMe').on("click", function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).data('destination');
});
```

EDIT: Actually, the plugin that you use have the functionality built into it already.  On your div add `data-link` attribute like below.  Read through all of its functionality here https://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/

```
<div  data-link="http://www.google.com" data-src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slideshow/banner1.png"}}">
```